# Missing Paperclip methods when updating Ruby, Rails and gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, paperclip

I've updated my gem file to Ruby 2.5, Rails 4.2.10, paperclip 4.3.6 and devise 4.4.2 and I now get method missing errors for devise and then paperclip.  Why? What extra needs to be done to correctly update?

```
 `method_missing': undefined method `devise'
```

I can get round the devise errors by adding this:

```
extend Devise::Models
```

to my user models.

I then get the error

```
`method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file'
```

in my models that have paperclip methods.

Should I now be including gems into models manually like that? I don't think so.  So, what needs to be done to re-enable the autoloading?

Previous versions:

```
Ruby 2.2.0
Rails 4.1.8
Devise 3.5.6
paperclip 4.1.1
```

I've also tried updating to more recent devise and paperclip versions, which hasn't resolved it.

Comment: Smells like you did not `bundle install` after ruby update.

Comment: no that's not it @mudasobwa

Comment: @Will try to update devise/paperclip gems also.

Comment: I have.  in the question it should moving up to the latest 4 version, but I've also since tried moving to the actual latest versions.

Comment: i tried to update not to many version leaps at once to make it easier.

Comment: @7urkm3n - sorry, realised i was missing that info in the question.  updated

Comment: @Will did you run `bundle update`? Just changing your gem file shares your intentions but does not actually perform the operation for you. Was your server still running when you changed the Gemfile? If so shutdown bundle update restart

Comment: Did you consider reverting the change and update each gem on its own? Updating multiple gems at the same time makes it very hard to understand which update causes the issue.

Comment: @spickermann thats what I ended up doing in the end.